# IIS 7 Reverse Proxy With SSL?

Tags: iis-7, reverse-proxy

Which IIS 7 ISAPI Filter can help me doing that :

http://site1.domain1.com:80 ==> Internal IIS Server 1 (HTTP, TCP 80)

https://site2.domain1.com:443 ==> Internal IIS Server 1 (HTTPS, TCP 443)

http://site1.domain2.com:80 ==> Internal IIS Server 2 (HTTP, TCP 80)

http://site2.domain2.com:443 ==> Internal IIS Server 2 (HTTPS, TCP 443)

http://site1.domain3.com:80 ==> Internal IIS Server 2 (HTTP, TCP 8080)

http://site2.domain3.com:443 ==> Internal IIS Server 2 (HTTPS, TCP 8443)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a Reverse Proxy with IIS 7 using the URL Rewrite Module 2 and the Application Request Routing Module (ARR).

I didn't try it myself but the following link should be able to solve your problem:

[Reverse Proxy with URL Rewrite v2 and Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing)